# SQL: apply "where in" on select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to select some users based on another table.

### Table structures

`users` table

```
id     name
1      John
2      sarah
3      nick
```

`level` table

```
id     list
1      1,2
2      3,5,6
3      1,2,3
```

I tried

```
select *
from users
where id in (select list from level where id = 2)
```

But this does not return any data. Any ideas how to retreive correct result?

Comment: Welcome to MySQL. Now see normalization.

Comment: Your query would return `...id in ("3,5,6")...` which is a single string. What you need is `...id in (3,5,6)...`

Comment: @Bala and no way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5309d/1/0)):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id ,(select list from level where id = 2)) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select *
from users
where 
    FIND_IN_SET(id ,(select list from level where id = 2)) <> 0
```

Comment: **@Kewal**, nice answer, but I have the same answer and beat you by 8 minutes.